# Why does insert query results remain in database after transaction rollback? pg-promise

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I have recently implemented pg-promise into one of my projects and am trying to understand how the transactions function. I am testing with the following function:

```
testFunction: (req, res, next) => {
    db.tx(async t =>{
         await db.any('insert into services (servicename, price, itemcode, servicedescription, active, subscriptionid) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) returning *;', ['babysitting', 25, '12321', 'taking care of children', true, 1])
         await db.any('insert into orangutans (name, age, sex) values ($1, $2, $3)', ['beau', 22, 'male'])
    })
    .then(data=>{
        res.json(data)
    })
    .catch(error=>{
        res.json(error)
    })
}
```

I modeled this piece of code after the following example in the pg-promise documentation:

```
db.tx(async t => {
    await t.none('UPDATE users SET active = $1 WHERE id = $2', [true, 123]);
    await t.one('INSERT INTO audit(entity, id) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING id', ['users', 123]);
})
    .then(data => {
        // success, COMMIT was executed
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // failure, ROLLBACK was executed
    });
```

The first query runs successfully and inserts a record into the database. The second query fails because the relationship 'orangutans' does not exist. I expected the record inserted by the first query to be removed from the database as part of the transaction rollback. When I check the database following the execution of this code the record remains in the database. Can someone please point me in the right direction to understand why the record was not removed?

Answer (score 1):

I saw my answer as soon as I opened the question to review it. I was calling .any on 'db' rather than 't'. It worked as soon I made this change.

Comment: Yeah, use of the wrong connection context inside transactions can lead to some messy results. You must always use the right connection context provided by the transaction.